# Creating a Hibernate reference in a client app

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to add a relation to a detached entity. For that I want to use an entity reference created by ID. All the examples that I have found and understood need a configured DB connection to create references. As in this example:

`reference = session.byId( EmployeeEntity.class ).getReference( 1 );`

I'm using this in a client program and am accessing the DB indirectly through remote EJBs, so I don't have direct access to the DB. Is it possible to create an entity reference without a DB connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: In theory you could write your own persistence strategy and plug it into Hibernate to talk to remote EJBs, but this would be a lot of work, doesn't have any notable benefits except making you an expert of a rather obscure corner of the hibernate environment.

Comment: Hibernate shouldn't be talking to anyone in the client. I only need a detached entity with an ID, without checking if it actually exists. I figure that does not need any DB connection. I guess I'll have to look for routines specifically generating the references/proxies.

Comment: What do you mean by Hibernate shouldn't talk to anyone in the client? you are using Hibernate in the client. The only purpose of Hibernate is to talk to a database. If you don't want that, just create a new instance using the constructor. ???

Comment: I thought the references/proxies had to be created using Hibernate. Now that I tested it, it appears an object created with a constructor and ID set is sufficient to add to a relationship. Thanks!